# Sync two different Scrollviewers in Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, scrollviewer

In my application I have two different set of ItemsControl which will be having Horizontal ScrollViewer to view the Items in the Viewport. But two ItemsControls will be having the Items with the different widths.

So I set the HorizontalOffset of one ScrollViewer to HorizontalOffset of other ScrollViewer.
But in the above case if we try to scroll one of the ScrollViewer, its not syncing with others as it is having different set of Item widths. Is there any way to achieve the synchronization of scrollviewer in this case with any factor calculation ?

Could you please anyone help me in this ?